# Getting really slow response from @google-cloud/translate

Tags: google-translate

I have been using the @google-cloud/translate package in my project for some time now and usually response times took between 800ms and 1.3s for the entire api call.
Suddenly it started taking between 8s and 12s.
I tried looking in the GCP graphs and it says there there is only a 25-250ms delay there.

What might be the cause?
Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem, translation takes 3seconds..

Comment: Same for me. Sometimes it takes almost 30-40 seconds. Did you find anything that help to solve this?

Comment: Happens to me as well. Generally only occurs when we make > 10k req/min. It's also infrequent and transient making it hard to exactly reproduce.